# What actions can I take to safely convince others that I am a bad player?

Tags: tells

In a live casino (specifically 3 rivers casino) NLH $1/$2 I would like to be labeled as the table idiot. My plan is to come in on a Saturday night after the Pirates play their ballgame while wearing Pirate's gear from head to toe(or the other team's logos if that would work better) and smelling of beer. While there I am going to have a beer at all times, get caught bluffing on some small hands, try to get the worst hands to the show-down for cheap, and maybe try a short maniac spree. As soon as people start playing like I am that fool i aimed to be, I then shift to the standard Tag/weak play that I find profitable.

What other techniques could I employ to make people undermine my ability to play poker?

Is this profitable in general?

*I AM NOT INSULTING BASEBALL FANS, I AM SIMPLY IMPLYING THAT THE MOST OBVIOUSLY CASUAL PLAYER AT MY LOCAL CASINO WOULD BE COMING IN ON A SATURDAY NIGHT AFTER SEEING THE PIRATES LOSE.

*consumption of alcohol will not alter my playing.(I don't care that you don't believe me)

Comment: Being talkative is all you need if you want to create an aggressive table image.

Comment: Try to be more _Tony G_ and _Poker Brat_, they trying to do exactly what you want. In any case, trying to play the opposite of your original style may shows better results than trying to look more idiot on the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Move allin preflop with nut carts lol. They won't know until it hits them. If you're not afraid to gamble try shove every AQs+.
- Choose your bet sizing randomly.(PF 5 BB next hand 2 BB)(people will think you can not play)
- Reraise someone and than show him the bluff(people will think you are drunk and will play like a maniac all the time).
- Say raise but just throw only one blind or less.(people will think you are drunk and can not play)
- Throw your cards in the muck but throw them in a way that they turn around.(do it multiple times people will get annoyed).
- When you know you lost the hand at the river. If the guy is gona raise. Show your hand and say you won.(And than say you thought he checked back,since you're supposed to be a bit drunk they would understand).(people will think you are stupid and drunk)
- Raise lets say 5 big blinds but put them in the table one by one.
- Talk a lot of none sense stuff related or not to the game.(people will want to crush you because you're annoying).Say that you're the best and played everywhere with pros.

Anything annoying works you can come up with million of ideas

Comment: oh wow, thanks for the great set of ideas. Time for some fun.

Answer (score -2):

That's angle shooting and it's illegal in poker. Angling is any type of fraud. Because poker involves money, attempting to manipulate another player in any manner in order to make that person part with their money is fraudulent.

Poker is civilized game. Ethics and etiquette play a large part in poker and cheating, such as Angling and player deceit, will be quickly detected by Casinos (who have professionals watching many high resolution cameras in back rooms). Trying to fool other players will not be tolerated in a Casino. Such illegal activity (such as deliberate deceit) committed at a Casino's poker tables will usually result in a lifetime ban to player angling to gain unfair advantage for many reasons, including legislative and legal reasons (such as risk to their Casino gambling licenses).

Play your hand and use the information the game offers. Do not try to influence other players through fraudulent means to part with their money as that is not Poker, it's some other game that you are playing and those in charge will soon sniff out the lie and eject you from the game.

As an example, there was a recent 2017 PLO tourney where a player attempted to take advantage by convincing others he was inept. What this corrupt character did was he would put in calling chips while announcing "Raise." He then immediately says, "Sorry! Call!"

The problem is the cheater/angler knows the Floor/Tournament Director/Dealer will enforce his verbal "Raise" declaration as verbal declarations stand in poker. What this cheater/angler is trying to do, however, is appear weaker than he is by trying to suggest he never intended to to make the "raise" (thus committing to a minimum-raise) he has now verbally locked himself in to make. The other player sitting there now thinks, "This guy can't be all that strong, I'll call or even re-raise or even shove all-in."

So here's the rest of the story: The problem is this angle-shooter has been caught on numerous occasions doing this when he has the absolute stone-cold-nuts - an unbeatable hand. Casino's keep good records that they share with each other. A cheater/fraudster/angler will be well known everywhere if they are persistent in their cheating of other players. In this scenario, the angler/corrupt player has attempted to fabricate a story that his holdings are moderate or not strong and he is further selling the story as being the result of his incompetence - he's effectively deliberately lying to, and telling the other player, "I have modest holdings and in my incompetence I can't even get the words 'raise' and 'call' right." All the while, this fraudster/angler is holding a monster hand that would crush his opponent. In this case the Angler (who like the poster of the question here on this webpage wants to appear incompetent to gain advantage) is holding a Full House compared to his victim's two pair (including top-pair) hand.

Well, needless the say the Tournament Director is already aware of this angler and immediately steps in and warns everyone involved and watching of the angler/cheater's fraudulent intent. The angler/player receives a final warning later that he will be banned for life if he tries the behavior again against another customer of the Casino.

If you want to find the video search for "Etiquette sickest angle shoot ever" posted around February of 2017.

Bottom line, fraud is illegal, and both elements of fraud (money and deliberate deception) are present in your question's intention. If you want to cheat, poker isn't for you and in the wrong game, it can have serious life-altering consequences. Also, you have a gambling problem in that you think winning at poker is a foregone conclusion to the point you are so good you just have to trick others into staying at the tables.

Comment: I would hardly call what OP is asking "angle shooting", nor is that what he's asking for.